# Manually installing app in iOS 8.3 simulator using symlink does not work

Tags: ios, simulator, ios8.3

I have built an app installer for iOS simulators that places the .app file in a local directory that is symlinked into all iOS 8 simulator device paths where the apps live (`~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<Device ID>/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/`). This works great except for iOS 8.3 simulators.

It looks like iOS 8.3 simulators do not respect the symlink. If I move the .app file into a regular directory inside the 8.3 simulator, the app shows up fine.

Any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: So you're doing something completely unsupported and then you're wondering why it isn't supported?

Comment: @matt I was just wondering if there was a workaround to this problem or if someone was similarly affected. The benefit of symlinking all of the simulator devices to a common .app is so I don't have to copy it into every single simulator app directory (sorry if I'm stating the obvious). At my company, the app installer is quite useful for distributing apps to the sales and support team for client demos.

Comment: Why not write a simple script that does `xcrun simctl install` for your app on all simulators? Not hard.